# How to infer generic type based on provided Record values in typescript?

Tags: typescript, generics, typescript-typings, typescript-generics, type-inference

I have a polymorficFactory function, that will instantiate classes based on the 'discriminator' property provided:

```js
type ClassConstructor<T> = {
    new (...args: any[]): T;
};
type ClassMap<T> = Record<string, ClassConstructor<T>>;

function polymorficFactory<T extends object>(
  classMap: ClassMap<T>,
  discriminator: string,
  input: Record<string, any>,
): T {
  if (!input[discriminator]) throw new Error('Input does not have a discriminator property');

  const discriminatorValue = input[discriminator];
  const constructor = classMap[discriminatorValue];

  return plainToInstance(constructor, input); // class-transformer util
}
```

It's used on unknown objects coming from request payloads:

```js
const MOCK_PAYLOAD = {
  type: 'SOME_DTO',
  someProperty: 1,
  someStr: 'Lorem',
  someNestedProp: {
    someBool: true,
  }
} as as Record<string, unknown>; // Record<string, unknown/any>, since comes from JSON payload, but will always be an object
const dto = polymorficFactory<SomeDto | SomeOtherDto>(
  {
    SOME_DTO: SomeDto,
    SOME_OTHER_DTO: SomeOtherDto,
  },
  'type',
  MOCK_PAYLOAD ,
);

dto; // when hovering, type will be "SomeDto | SomeOtherDto"
```

If I wont provide the type parameters:

```js
const dto = polymorficFactory(
  ...
);

dto; // when hovering, type will be "SomeDto"
```

It selects the first value it finds in this object:

```js
{
  SOME_DTO: SomeDto,
  SOME_OTHER_DTO: SomeOtherDto,
}
```

Is there a way that I can make ts infer the union type, `SomeDto | SomeOtherDto` or any other Dto classes found in the provided classMap, from the map values, without explicitly providing it?

I.e., for the following classMap:

```js
{
  A: aDto,
  B: bDto,
  C: cDto,
}
```

I'd expect the following union type inferred for the result:
`aDto | bDto | cDto`

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzmANgQ2AOwCoQJKYDOMamAxgKZwC+cAZlBCHAORnqGEC0MUphdaCApQWAbgBQEmAE8wVAMIdCCiEV4BXMjGgAebAD44AXkQS4FuJgoB3OAAoAdM7RQA5oQBccUjIDaALoAlN7YktSSsvJwSmicALJoYPpGpgBKFGTQACa6xFBYbgA0Mcqq6lBaOlApBpISdBrkMMBqyBAoMiDQdMBkAGJo2tAy+nAUAB4wFJjZhHAQAEYAVpkwBvbmcOxxhIlg3rEJSSlFW9nAhGQFIFho1d75hWcWWGAaMN4ZWVC5T5jFHyYGQGM4hODYMyvOgOACEbw+fguVxud2qwTgMAAFow7NY7ABRKCMKD2FgEd7wbIQCjzTAQeBYtAANyoaDgyOuoDR0GQjHksBkLCC9QsWXUHMuXNumHu0AAamgUBoqKYETAkVLUbL0ZIxWpiNsDZphlATNtlPtNSjuTqFUqVQFRXAoBQYBooJhkOgsLgCMRSJR7OL8lVoCV1UEfPMwhJqFIdpw4ABlJgUAAiOkQ8cT81TwgA8tiRJmINmJCH4AoADIAQWTyYA+vFawAFc0ILYWZMF+IExvp7AF7z5jM6F6WHt9xsF7AACQJaQHQ5HaaLWJL47jFeNcFbtYAmtWC7X082CwoANIdrZRCjeFhT-uDgssCeENOt-kiWTeACM75psmvAPtW0AUCAb5bB+wgAHK0tM2RfhABxQpYMEUAAQhAHTeJoFATvGtBxHA3w5HkvDPHATQANb0jYmB1HAAD0zGkZk5H-ICtH0ZgzG+KCcCEFglBGsI8wMEwcAAFI9rByBoDIKAQGg2QlIsHxwDYwAoCgPgoDYinzIsbJeksqzaDuEqTKgfTADArauGgIDzKYkCdN0UC9AMQzVKMo6lnAAA+KZrsWUClhsWw1vWTYtq2E4sHeUEWPuR4nme8QXpeYL1DZKB2Q5TkuWILFsTYG5eliECsgUAIlHeWk6XpJlwAARAFWYhaO66bhAbUJruoC2WQ9mOXwLnmu5XQ9H0gymjImwWDFDbNm2iXJROaXHqe55XrlUjDQVo1FRNhClaxWmVXA1W1VRjXabpcCtR1YUbhFOgDUAA)

Comment: Maybe like [this](https://tsplay.dev/WGAMVN)? Explicit params will be a fair bit more annoying to use, but it makes implicit params work.

Comment: This is exactly what was needed, although the assertion at the return statement irks me a little bit. Is there any way to tighten up the types and avoid assertion? Feel free to post this as an answer, as it achieves the goal of the question.

Comment: No assertion needed when passing generics to `plainToInstance`: https://tsplay.dev/WvGRkw

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to play with inference on function arguments a little bit. The rule of thumb:
If you want to infer a value, you should replay all transformations which are done in a runtime in type scope.

I mean if you build a class instance, you need to call `InstanceType` built in type in order to get class instance type.

These class maps worth making immutable or in other words use `as const` assertion.

COnsider this:

```js
import { plainToInstance } from "class-transformer";

type ClassConstructor<T> = {
  new(...args: any[]): T;
};

function polymorficFactory<
  Inst,
  Values extends PropertyKey,
  Discriminator extends string,
  ClassMap extends Record<Values, ClassConstructor<Inst>>,
  Input extends Record<Discriminator, Values>
>(
  classMap: ClassMap,
  discriminator: Discriminator,
  input: Input,

): InstanceType<ClassMap[Input[Discriminator]]>
function polymorficFactory<
  Inst,
  Values extends PropertyKey,
  Discriminator extends string,
  ClassMap extends Record<Values, ClassConstructor<Inst>>,
  Input extends Record<Discriminator, Values>
>(
  classMap: ClassMap,
  discriminator: Discriminator,
  input: Input,

) {
  if (!input) throw new Error('Input is not an object');
  if (!input[discriminator]) throw new Error('Input does not have a discriminator property');

  const discriminatorValue = input[discriminator];
  const klass = classMap[discriminatorValue];
  const result = plainToInstance(klass, input)

  return result
}

class SomeDto {
  tag = 'SomeDto'
}

class SomeOtherDto {
  tag = 'SomeOtherDto'
}

const CLASS_MAP = {
  SOME_DTO: SomeDto,
  SOME_OTHER_DTO: SomeOtherDto,
} as const

const MOCK = {
  type: 'SOME_OTHER_DTO',
  someProperty: 1,
} as const

const explicitParams = polymorficFactory(
  CLASS_MAP,
  'type',
  MOCK,
);

explicitParams; // when hovering, type will be " SomeOtherDto"
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/wEBM3N)

As you might have noticed each value in `polymorficFactory` is infered properly.

1. See this line `const discriminatorValue = input[discriminator];` . If you expect `discriminator` to be a valid index for `input`, you should apply appropriate constraint:

```js
function polymorficFactory<
  // .....
  Values extends PropertyKey,
  Discriminator extends string,
  Input extends Record<Discriminator, Values>
>(
  // ...
  discriminator: Discriminator,
  input: Input,
)
```

`input` variable should extend `Record<Discriminator, Values>`. It means that `discriminator` is allowed index for `input`.

Consider this line `const klass = classMap[discriminatorValue];`

`discriminatorValue` which is `input[discriminator]` should be a valid key for `classMap`, hence, we need to apply here an appropriate constraint:

```js
function polymorficFactory<
  Inst,
  Values extends PropertyKey,
  Discriminator extends string,
  ClassMap extends Record<Values, ClassConstructor<Inst>>,
  Input extends Record<Discriminator, Values>
>(
  classMap: ClassMap,
  discriminator: Discriminator,
  input: Input,

)
```

See `Values` generic, it plays a role of `value` in `Input` and a key in `ClassMap`. It is important.

So now, when all arguments are infered, we need to infer a return type. Our return type is an instance of `classMap[input[discriminator]]`, or in `type` words: `InstanceType<ClassMap[Input[Discriminator]]>`

If you are interested in more explanation of inference on function arguments, you can check my [article](https://catchts.com/infer-arguments)

Comment: In my case the input is an unknown, it comes from a json payload - hence the checks at the begging. The idea is to provide a map of dtos and their classes, and mark the resulting class as one of the provided classes in the map values. Unfortunately once I undo the `MOCK as const` or mark it as `any/unknown` - it will fail to infer the union type. But even if the input was known - I'm not sure why the Input object values are constrained to Values(aka PropertyKey, aka string/num/symb). The article is fascinating by the way.

Comment: @EcksDy thank you for your feedback. Could you please provide an example with `unknown` input ?

Comment: I've update the question and the playground link. [The comment by caTS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74351543/how-to-infer-generic-type-based-on-provided-record-values-in-typescript#comment131261679_74351543) achieved what I tried to do, but used assertion for the return statement. It gets the job done, but I wonder if it's possible without asserting the return value.

Comment: @EcksDy check [this](https://tsplay.dev/NVb1GN). I have also added assertion functions

Comment: I've managed to simplify it [here](https://shorturl.at/jsDRT). It seems that the functionality I needed comes from `ValueOf<T>` and the added signature above the function body. If I remove it and try to mark the function return type as `InstanceType<ValuesOf<ClassMap>>` it will obviously clash with the returned value type `Inst`. Why is it not clashing with the returned result when an additional signature is added? Any good resource to read up on this behavior?

Comment: @EcksDy please provide an example. The link you have added is broken

Comment: [I basically removed Values, and am not sure why adding a separate signature doesn't cause an error.](https://cutt.ly/1MqO4Fb) @captain-yossarian-from-ukraine

Comment: @EcksDy this is because I overloaded `polymorficFactory`. As you might have noticed, there are two type declarations for  `polymorficFactory`. When input generic is a part of return type, in 99% cases it will be an error because TS considers it as an unsafe code, this is why I have overloaded this function , it allows you to infer return type. Please be aware that function overloading are bivariant, it means that it is not 100%, however it is ussual practice in TypeScript